# crontab not working under arch linux

Tags: linux, bash, find, cron

I tried to set up a schedule to remove the old file and folder after several days. I put the following code in a script file and tried to use crontab to run it every day. The find command worked fine. but the crontab seems not execute the script file.

I also use crontab for other tasks, i.e. rsync, they all work fine. I am wondering what might be the possible reason that crontab won't work in this case. And what could I do alternatively for the job? Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash -x

find /media -type d -ctime +18 | xargs rm -rf
```

my crontab entries are

```
10 09 * * * /root/rsync-shell.sh &
20 09 * * * /root/chg3gp2avi.sh &
30 09 * * * /root/clean_files_10days.sh &
```

the first two are the ones I set up before and work fine. The third one is the current one that won't work.

Comment: please edit your question to include your crontab entry. Good luck.

Comment: Does your `crontab` work for other scripts?

Comment: what does your cron log say?

Comment: Have you considered using [tmpreaper](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/tmpreaper/)?  It removes old files.  It is very configurable.  It would get you out of the business of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Just a point, this will delete directories, assuming they were created more than 18 days ago, weren't moved in the last 18 days, and otherwise had no inode status change in the last 18 days, regardless of whether any files within the directories were more recently modified, created, or deleted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! See the [crontab tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) for tips on what to look for. Edit the question with your findings!

Comment: @BroSlow Thanks. I am aware of that. My webcam upload photos regularly and create a folder every day, so it won't put new photos into old folder. This simple command fits my situation.

Comment: @clement I can't find the crontab log under Arch linux yet. not in /var/log. My previous jobs work fine so I didn't think about the log before. I'll keep searching where it is located under Arch Linux.

Comment: @lurker yes my crontab work for other scripts

Comment: Why do you have ampersand at the end of each `crontab` task? It's not necessary to make them background since `crontab` already runs in the background.

Comment: Who is the owner of the files under `/media`? Are you creating the `crontab` using `crontab -e` under the same user that has permission to delete files from that directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is crond running?

```
$ systemctl status crond
* crond.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

If not try to start it before debugging any further. If you have not configured sudo then use root privileges by some other means, such as logging in as root or via su command.

```
$ sudo systemctl start crond
```

Comment: Thanks Sami. I just found that my old script stopped running for a while then I figure cron was somehow disable a while ago. I enable it and now all of them go back to normal status. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

It's renamed into cronie, so:

```txt
    systemctl enable cronie
    systemctl start cronie
```

double-check:

```sh
    ps aux | grep crond
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer, but mainly because it solved my problem compared to the other answer which did not.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam no need, it's points makes that point themselves. And.. SEO.